# can we use "to worry about" & "to be worried about" interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage

> **to worry**: to keep thinking about unpleasant things that might happen
>   or about problems that you have [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/worry_1?q=worry)
>
> Ex: *Don't worry about me. I'll be all right*.
>
> **to be worried about**: thinking about unpleasant things that have
>   happened or that might happen and therefore feeling unhappy and afraid [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/worried?q=worried)
>
> Ex: *I'm not worried about her—she can take care of herself*.

So, can I say "*Don't be worried about me. I'll be all right*" & "*I don't worry about her—she can take care of herself*"

can we use "*to worry about*" & "*to be worried about*" interchangeably?

Comment: yes, you can use. You just changed from 'to worry' to 'to be worried'. Because when you 'worry', that 'worry' makes you 'worried'!